# Question about tensor products, decomposable tensors, ...

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I need some help with the following problem:

> Let $V_1,\ldots,V_m$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{K}$.
>
> Let $\varphi \in L(V_1,\ldots,V_m;U)$ such that $Im(\varphi)=U$.
>
> Show that there exists a subspace $K$ of $V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_m$ such that every class of $\frac{V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_m}{K}$ contains a decomposable tensor.

I have some ideas but none of them work, such as:

$$U = Im(\varphi) \simeq \frac{V_1 \times \cdots \times V_m}{Ker(\varphi)}$$

which is wrong because $\varphi$ is multilinear and not linear, so I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Any ideas? Hints? Thanks!

> If you know where I can find this problem (maybe in some book) I would be very grateful.

Comment: Your last equation doesn't make sense because $\varphi$ is not a homomorphism.

Comment: $V_1 \times \cdots \times V_m$ and $U$ are vector spaces and $\varphi$ is linear (i.e. is a homomorphism of $\mathbb{K}$-modules (or $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces), so I can apply the homomorphism theorem. Am I wrong?

Comment: The part that is wrong: $\varphi$ is not linear, it is multilinear.

Comment: Ok, I will erase then

Comment: I think it's worth adding the ideas, even if they don't seem to work. Maybe I'm alone on this.

Comment: As written the problem has a gap: the "Show that..." part makes no use of $\varphi$, so $\varphi$ doesn't look relevant to the problem.  You could give a stupid answer like $K = V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_n$, for which the quotient space is zero.

Comment: Indeed, however the purpose of the problem is to find a non trivial $K$ using the fact that: $Im(\varphi)=U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the universal factorization property of $\otimes$, there exists a unique linear map $\psi: V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_m \longrightarrow U$ such that $\varphi = \psi \circ \otimes$.

As $\varphi$ is surjective, $\psi$ is surjective: given $u \in U$, $u = \varphi(v_1,\ldots,v_m)$ for some $(v_1,\ldots,v_m) \in V_1 \times \cdots \times V_m$, then $u = \psi \circ \otimes (v_1,\ldots,v_m) = \psi(v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_m)$, then $u \in Im(\psi)$.

So given $u \in U$, there exists $(v_1,\ldots,v_m) \in V_1 \times \cdots \times V_m$ such that
\begin{align*}
u = \psi(v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_m) = \varphi(v_1,\ldots,v_m).
\end{align*}

Let $K=Ker(\psi)$.

Then,
\begin{align*}
\pi: \frac{V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_m}{K} &\to U\\
z + Ker(\psi) &\mapsto \psi(z)
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism (easy to check).

Let us prove that each class of $\frac{V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_m}{K}$ contains a decomposable tensor.

If $z + K = K$ it is trivial because $0 \in K$ and $0$ is decomposable.

Suppose that there exists a class $z_0 + K \neq K$ such that $z_0 + K$ does not contain a decomposable tensor.

Then, it does not exist $z \in z_0 + K$ decomposable such that $\pi(z + K) = \psi(z) = u$, but this is false, since each $u \in U$ is of the form $\psi(v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_m)$ for some $(v_1,\ldots,v_m) \in V_1 \times \cdots \times V_m$ as we saw above.

So we conclude that each class of $\frac{V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_m}{K}$ contains a decomposable tensor.

Answer (score 2):

By the [universal property of the tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property), $\varphi$ induces a linear map $\psi\colon V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_m \to U$ which is also surjective (why?). And in fact we know more: for any $u \in U$, because $\varphi$ is surjective there are $v_i \in V_i$ such that $\varphi(v_1, \dots, v_m) = \psi(v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_m) = u$. I'm hoping that from here you can fill in a gap. Thinking about the first isomorphism theorem is a good idea, though I don't think you need to apply it directly.

Comment: Thanks! I will think about it. Actually I also tried to use the universal factorization property of $\otimes$. I am going to try again then...

Comment: Ok, we have $U \simeq \frac{V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_m}{Ker(\psi)}$, so I let $K = Ker(\psi)$. We have $\frac{V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_m}{Ker(\psi)} = \{v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_m + Ker(\psi) : v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_m \in V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_m\}$

Comment: We know that for any $u \in U$, $u$ is the image of a decomposable tensor, so each class of $\frac{V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_m}{Ker(\psi)}$ is of the form $v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_m + Ker(\psi)$. As $0 \in Ker(\psi)$, $v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_m$ is in the class, so we can conclude that that each class of $\frac{V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_m}{Ker(\psi)}$ contains a decomposable tensor. Right?

Comment: @Leafar Yes, that sounds right.